# Build output on AWS CodeDeploy pipeline

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline

I have setup a pipeline on AWS CodeDeploy.
[image]

My bildspec.yml has a line that runs react build script, and judging by pipeline build output the build runs ok.
[image]
[image]

Yet, in the final image that is deployed, only the repo files exist, react's build output folder is not there.
On localhost this works ok.

I have read a ton of AWS documentation and googled examples, and I can't understand what's wrong.

Comment: Can you try by adding the line base-directory: 'build_dir' in the artifacts section of buildspec file?

Comment: @DeependraDangal yep, tried that - no change... :(

Answer (score 1):

The output build will not be added to the repository of CodeCommit. It will be stored in the S3 bucket you specified in the artifacts section of CodeBuild.

If you still want to store the build in the CodeCommit, the create an Event to lambda from that s3 bucket. Then use boto3 put_file operation of CodeCommit in a lambda to push that s3 file to CodeCommit. For reference: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/codecommit.html#codecommit

Comment: No, i dont want to store the build in CodeCommit. I want it to be part of final deployed folder